# MomentJS Date parsing

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having trouble understanding the the following returns false:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckkyLLrc/

```
console.log(moment("Mar 30, 2016 4:43:49 PM", "MMM dd, YYYY H:m:s a").isValid());
```

It seems to be related to the "AM", however everything appears correct according to the MomentJS docs. Any ideas?

Comment: `Mar 30, 2016 AM` doesn't make sense as a date string.

Comment: console.log(moment("Mar 30, 2016 4:43:49 PM", "MMM dd, YYYY H:m:s a").isValid());
Doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (see the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8v14dt8/)):

```
console.log(moment("Mar 30, 2016 4:43:49 PM", "MMM DD, YYYY H:mm:ss A").isValid()); // true
```

and this

```
console.log(moment("Mar 30, 2016 4:43:49 PM", "MMM DD, YYYY H:m:s A").isValid()); // true
```

Looks like `dd` needed to be `DD`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `a` am/pm input with a 12 hour time input. Your example is with a date.

See the MomentJS [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
H HH    0..23   24 hour time
h hh    1..12   12 hour time used with a A.
a A     am pm   Post or ante meridiem (Note the one character a p are also considered valid)
```

Comment: 4:43:49 PM is clearly a 12 hour time - is there a way to parse a date/time combination like in my example?

Comment: Original post had `Mar 30, 2016 AM` before edits.

`console.log(moment("Mar 30, 2016 4:43:49 PM", "MMM DD, YYYY H:mm:ss A").isValid());` works, as @Josh Beam posted above